# Operation between complex numbers whose answer is not complex

Tags: complex-numbers

Is there such an operation? What kind of number would the answer be?

There is an operation between real numbers whose answer is not real: $\sqrt{-1} = (-1)^{1/2} = i$. However, operations between complex numbers such as $\sqrt{i} = i^{1/2} = e^{i\pi/4}$ and $i^i = e^{-\pi/2}$ (principal value) result in complex numbers.

It is known that [the solutions of algebraic equations with complex coefficients are always complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

The values of functions such as $i! = \Gamma(1 + i) \approx 0.4980 - 0.1549i$ are also complex numbers. Is there any function whose value is not complex for a complex input?

One thing that came to my mind is $^i i = \underbrace {i^{i^{\cdot^{\cdot^i}}}}_{i \text{ times}}$, the "$i$th" [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) of $i$, but according to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/280343), although I don't understand it, the value still seems to be complex.

---

**Edit:**

I found a [duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1094965). The answer there seems to be "there is no such algebraic operation by the fundamental theorem of algebra."

My question is not limited to algebraic operations, but I can't seem to find any such [mathematical function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_functions). Then the question arises as to *why* there are none.

I wonder if this is because when we extend numbers from complex numbers to, say, quaternions, we lose properties such as commutativity, so mapping to such a larger domain is not very useful.

Comment: Welcome. You're essentially asking for a function $f:\Bbb C\to X$ for some $X$ which is "not $\Bbb C$". Such functions are legion. That's also not a satisfying answer, I'm sure.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that concern. I wanted to ask if there are any "standard" operations or functions. And only defined ones, excluding $0/0$, etc.

Comment: Do you count real numbers as "not complex"? If so, take $|z|$; if not, take $zj$ with $j\in\Bbb H$, which maps $x+yi$ with $x,\,y\in\Bbb R$ to $xj+yk$, if we identify $i\in\Bbb C$ with $i\in\Bbb H$.

Comment: @J.G. Real numbers are complex. Is it an operation "between" complex numbers? And is it not "artificial"? For quaternions I found a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2999500) but no answer. My question wasn't specifically with quaternions in mind.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I guess what you're hoping for is a map outside of $\Bbb C$ whose definition doesn't mention anything outside of $\Bbb C$, because $zj$ is "artificial" insofar as it has an explicit $j$ factor.

Comment: Example : **if** $z$ is any complex number of form $(x + iy) ~: ~x,y \in \Bbb{R}$, let $~\overline{z}~$ denote the complex conjugate of $z$.  That is, $~\overline{z}~ = (x - iy).~$  Then, both of the following expressions are guaranteed to produce a Real number: $$[z + \overline{z}] ~~~\text{and}~~~ [z \times \overline{z}].$$

Comment: @user2661923 I consider real numbers to be complex, i.e., I'm looking for an operation whose the answer is neither complex nor real (neither rational nor integer.)

Comment: Index the letters of the alphabet A,B,C,...,Z as $L_0, L_1, \cdots, L_{25}.$  Construct the function $$f:\Bbb{C} \to \{A,B,\cdots,Z\}$$ as follows: For $$k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,24\},$$ if $~k \leq |z| < (k+1),~$ then $~f(z) = L_k.~$ If $~25 \leq |z|,~$ then $~f(z) = L_{25}.$

Answer (score 0):

When we define a function on a set (the *domain*), we are essentially free to do so in whichever way we want. We have carte blanche over both the set being mapped to (the *codomain*) and the function value that corresponds to each argument, with the only restriction (and a very undemanding one at that) being that each argument can map to at most one value.

We can trivially define a function on the complex numbers that is equal to a constant, equal to some set of real numbers, or really anything else.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I wanted to ask if there are any meaningful, "standard" operations or functions that have some name or symbol attached to them.

Comment: @13870445 In that case, you will need to sensibly specify what you mean by a "standard" function. Given any function $f$ on the complex numbers, we have that its real part $\operatorname{Re} f(z)$ is purely real. By almost anyone's definition, the real part function is "standard". So, essentially all functions fit the bill.

Comment: It's certainly vague. I guess it could be "a special function, something of mathematical interest, with a name or symbol attached to it." I consider real numbers to be complex.